# Rails: Display dropdown menu with categories and subcategories

Tags: drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form where user selects sub-category of the product. I have a dropdown list to display all subcategories to choose from. This is the code in product form view:

```
    <%= collection_select :sub_category_id, @sub_categories, :id, :sub_category, {:include_blank => 'Select a Sub Category'} %>
```

In products controller:

```
     @sub_categories = SubCategory.all
```

In the same dropdown, i wanna show categories with sub-category. I don't want to create a new dropdown list for categories.

List like :

```
   City (state)
```

where city is subcategory and state is category.

SubCategory model has following relation with Category:

```
     belongs_to :category
```

Can anyone please help me? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do something like

```
<% f.select(:sub_category_id, SubCategory.all.collect{|sub| [sub.category,sub.id]}.sort 
{|a, b| a[0] <=> b[0]}, {:prompt => "Select Sub-Category"}
```

I may not be 100% correct if this is what you are after.